# Spread operator with one exclusion to merge objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am merging data from two arrays of objects based on a common property `URL` and `url` and I am using spread operator to add all the properties on the final array.

The problem is that if the common property `value` does not have the same `key` name, it will add "twice" that property, other than changing the property name or adding the properties one by one is there a way to exclude that property using spread operator.

```js
const data1 = [{
  url: 'google.com',
  private: 'no'
},{
  url: 'duckduckgo.com',
  private: 'yes'
}]


const data2 = [{
  URL: 'google.com',
  many: true,
  other: true,
  properties: true,
  dont: true,
  want: true,
  to: true,
  add: true,
  onebyone: true,
}]


const res = data2.map(obj => {
  const otherData = data1.find(({ url }) => url === obj.URL)

  return {
    ...obj,
    ...otherData
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The expected result would be to remove the 'duplicate' URL property and have just `url: google.com`

Comment: I am not really sure what you're after. Can you provide some expected output, please?

Comment: The expected result, is the same you get by running the code minus the `URL` property. Which 'repeats' in the form of `url: 'google.com'` and `URL: 'google.com'`

Comment: Simply de-structure `URL` separately and use `...others` or `...rest` to capture other props. Then, when populating, use only the `...others` and this will drop-off `URL`.

Comment: I would `delete otherData.url;` before adding it to the returned object .. since those "url" are supposed to have the same value

Comment: @jsN00b could you use my example and provide and anwser please?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I did that and run into problems by mutating the data that later on I needed to reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why don't you just remove the URL -field from the outcome?

```js
const res = data2.map(obj => {
  const otherData = data1.find(({ url }) => url === obj.URL)

  const result = {
    ...obj,
    ...otherData
  };
  delete result.URL;
  return result;
})
```

Comment: Cause it mutates the data

Comment: No it does not. The spread operation creates here a new object and the example is deleting the field from the new object.

Comment: I did something similar by deleting the property then later on I used the same data set and the URL was missing

Comment: If use delete against the original objects of the data, that will happen. But spread operation creates a new instance of the object, so it is safe.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

As noted by OP in comments,

> could you use my example and provide and anwser please

Please find below a working example. I think it's self-explanatory; however, if any questions, please post and will explain as needed.

```js
const data1 = [{
  url: 'google.com',
  private: 'no'
},{
  url: 'duckduckgo.com',
  private: 'yes'
}]


const data2 = [{
  URL: 'google.com',
  many: true,
  other: true,
  properties: true,
  dont: true,
  want: true,
  to: true,
  add: true,
  onebyone: true,
}]


const res = data2.map(({ URL, ...rest }) => {
  const otherData = data1.find(({ url }) => url === URL)

  return {
    ...rest,
    ...otherData
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

NOTE: Instead of `obj` we de-structure and access `URL` and `rest`. Then, when populating we simply skip `URL` and keep only `rest`. That's it.